# Why does POST without parameters not return JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a controller method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetUserData()
{
    return Json(GetCurrentUser());
}
```

I'm calling it $.ajax() through a method like this:

```
ServerCall: function (method, args, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: method,
            data: JSON.stringify(args),
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                if (callback) {
                    callback(result);
                }
            },
            error: function (err) {
            }
        });
    }
```

with the call being:

```
ServerCall('GetUserData', null, function(data){
});
```

As it is, when I make this call, $.ajax returns with success, but 'data' is null.  Debugging, responseText is empty.  On the server side, GetUserData is called, and it is returning a properly formatted Json object (I've gone so far as to create my own JSON ActionResult and verified that data is indeed being written to the response stream.

If I add a dummy parameter to the server side method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetUserData(string temp)
{
    return Json(GetCurrentUser));
}
```

everything works perfectly.  Browser is IE8.  My question is, can anyone explain why this is happening?

UPDATE:

Note workaround solution below:  I'd still be interested in knowing the root cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reproduce using Darin's code in IE8.  While I don't know the root cause, I think it has something to do with how IE8 JSON.stringify handles null.  Changing

```
data: JSON.stringify(args)
```

to

```
data: args ? JSON.stringify(args) : null
```

fixed the problem.

Note, the problem is intermittent - I was seeing failures in about one out of every ten calls.  With the change, over 100 tests, the failure rate was zero.

Answer (score 4):

No repro.

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetUserData()
    {
        return Json(new { foo = "bar" });
    }
}
```

`Index.cshtml` view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var serverCall = function (method, args, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: method,
            data: JSON.stringify(args),
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                if (callback) {
                    callback(result);
                }
            },
            error: function (err) {
            }
        });
    };

    serverCall('@Url.Action("GetUserData")', null, function (data) {
        alert(data.foo);
    });
</script>
```

result: `'bar'` is alerted (as expected).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time Darin.  What browser were you testing with out of curiosity?  I should have specified IE8 on my end